# Calculating cumulative sum chart using Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, google-earth-engine-python-api, sentinel-1

I would like to calculate cumulative sum chart for time series of 4 images time series sentinel-1. The formular for this is : S0=0, S1=S0 + (x1-x), S2=S1+(x2-x), S3=S2+(x3-x), S4= S3+(x4-x) where xi= time series of observation, and x is the mean of all observation. I only can caluclate the x  the mean of all observation but do not know how to do the whole fomular.

Could you help me with this?

My script is:

```
    ###imagery collection_FLOAT
    im_coll = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD_FLOAT') /
            .filterBounds(aoi) /
            .filterDate(ee.Date('2021-09-01'),ee.Date('2021-12-30')) /
            .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
    VV = im_coll.select(['VV'])
    VV_mean = VV.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/ic_iterating

Answer (score 1):

Like Oliver pointed out, you can `iterate()` over the collection. When you have a large collection where most imagery doesn't overlap, `iterate()` can fail. Then you can try to convert your collection to an array, then use `arrayAccum()`. It really depends what you need to do with these results, if you can go down the array route. I did add the fractional year to the array, which probably is useful in most cases. If you don't need it, you can simplify the implementation quite a lot.

This shows how you can implement this in JavaScript, but it should be easy enough for you to port to Python (get rid of `var` and add some `\`).

```
var VV = im_coll.select(['VV']).sort('system:time_start')
var VV_mean = VV.mean()

// Option 1 - iterate()
var cumSumCollection = ee.ImageCollection(
  VV.iterate(
    function (image, acc) {
      image = ee.Image(image)
      acc = ee.ImageCollection(acc)
      var last = ee.Image(acc.get('last'))
      var value = last
        .add(image.subtract(VV_mean))
        .unmask(last)
        .copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames())
      return acc
        .merge(ee.ImageCollection([value]))
        .set('last', value)
        
    },
    ee.ImageCollection([]).set('last', ee.Image(0).rename('VV'))
  )
)

// Option 2 - arrayAccum()
var vvArray = VV
  .map(function (image) {
    var fractionalYear = image.date().get('year').add(image.date().getFraction('year'))
    return image.addBands(ee.Image(fractionalYear).float())
  })
  .toArray()
var cumSumArray = vvArray
  .arraySlice(1, 0, 1)
  .subtract(VV_mean)
  .arrayAccum(0, ee.Reducer.sum())
  .arrayCat(vvArray.arraySlice(1, 1), 1)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/fdcbb360c0a5b79b790bfee7b615a9fc